# How to add a listener to the action overflow icon?

Tags: java, android

Instead of the action overflow icon opening a menu I would like it to immediately send the user to the settings page when it's clicked.

I know that in order to create the action overflow icon and have it open a menu this is the way you do it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.pab_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

So I replaced it with this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 8);
    return true;
}
```

Needless to say it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a menu item and make this always visible for the icon you can assign the overflow icon and set it to show always

So your pab_menu.xml will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/overflow_icon"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And your action handling:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 8);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actionbar is automatically adjustable if there is space for the icons they appear... Otherwise collapse in overflow... You can force appearance with "showAsAction" always. Generally, it is advisable to use "ifRoom".

Comment: If you have appcompat use "app:showAsAction"

Comment: I just tested it and it's working 100% as I wanted :)